# Is there a way to link to a specific jenkins pipeline stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to link to a specific jenkins pipeline stage to share that link with my team mates if there's any issue and to link github checks to it.

If I copy and paste the URL after clicking a stage it loads for the next person that clicks on it, so I'm wondering if there's any way to get this URL.